# My application is not running on iPhone/iPad but running fine on simulator

Tags: ios, debugging, swift2

I'm getting all the data from a server and parsing it using JSON. After getting each story, I made a class called `MyStory`.

```
class MyStory: NSObject
{
    var location  = ""
    var storyId = 0
    var title = ""
    var story = ""
    var AllImages = [Image]()

    var images = NSArray() {
        willSet(newValue){

           // print("newvalue \(newValue)")

            for obj in newValue {
                let img = Image(dictionary: obj as! [String : AnyObject])
                AllImages.append(img)

                //imagePaths.append(img.imagePath)
                let helper = HelperClass()

                var imageDetail = "http://www.sleeksolutions.net/saad/" + img.imagePath
                helper.imagepath.append(imageDetail)



                //print("counter: \(helper.imagepath.count)")

            }
        }
    }

    init(dictionary: [String:AnyObject]) {
        super.init()
        self.setValuesForKeysWithDictionary(dictionary)
    }

    override func setValue(value: AnyObject?, forKey key: String) {
        if key == "images"
        {
           // print("key = \(key) , value : \(value)")
        }
        //error occurs here.
        super.setValue(value, forKey: key)
    }

}
```

And this function is called by the class `SeeStories`. Here is the code:

```
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
request.timeoutInterval = 10
request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request)
{
    (dat, res, er) in

    if er == nil
    {
        do
        {
            print("m hereeee")
            self.serverStatus = true

            let  jsonObject = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dat!, options: .MutableContainers)
            let arr = jsonObject as! NSDictionary

            //print(jsonObject)

            let storiees = arr["stories"] as! NSArray

            for obj in storiees{
                //Calling to MyStory Class here
                let s = MyStory(dictionary: obj as! [String : AnyObject])
                self.stories.append(s)

                let stat = self.fetch(s)

                if stat == false
                {
                    self.saveInCoreData(s)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Here is the picture of error in terminal]

Comment: add a exception breakpoint

Comment: Please show me the code in `setValuesForKeysWithDictionary` method

Comment: Are you using any external library ?

Comment: How to add exception breakpoint Shubhank

Comment: No im just using Haneke for caching the images

Comment: zylenv: Sir setValuesForKeysWithDictionary(dictionary) function is a public extension function of NSObject. I think this is objective - C function. DOnt know really

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html   `how to set a breakpoint`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the dictionary you are getting (which you use to create a `MyStory` object). From the looks of it, `storyId` is returned as a `String` and you try to save it into a `long`. `storyId` should be setup as a `String` variable instead

```
class MyStory: NSObject
{
    var location  = ""
    var storyId = "" //THIS instead of = 0
    var title = ""
    var story = ""...
```

I could be wrong but this is my best guess from the error log shown in your question.

Comment: I did this but nothing useful. You are right the error is occurs on storyId I add the exception breakpoint. But I am unable to solve this. My app is working fine on simulator.

Comment: Do you mind showing us what one of the dictionaries looks like? That might give a clue

Comment: With your Help StoryId error is resolved but it haas an another error on imagePath.

class Image: NSObject {
    
    var path = "http://www.sleeksolutions.net/saad/"
    var imageId: Int = 0
    var imagePath: String = ""
    var imageURL:String {
        return self.path+imagePath
    }
    
    
    init(dictionary: [String:AnyObject]) {
        super.init()
        // here is the error
        self.setValuesForKeysWithDictionary(dictionary)
    }
}

Comment: {
    images =     (
                {
            imageId = 12;
            imagePath = "uploads/test-1469597755.01398.jpg";
        }
    );
    location = Karachi;
    story = "Hello Every One";
    storyId = 43;
    title = IOS;
}
this is the one information of dictionary which i fetched from my server

Comment: Please see this link it has the image of error and dictionary you want to see. Also complete error. Make sure that previous error is gone now i have change the storyId = 0 to storyId = ""
https://www.dropbox.com/s/3xak2ze5aqu3j13/saveerror.JPG?dl=0

Comment: Whole Dictionary Data Link: It will be helpfull for you: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/16rzq7wnr67ws3o/dictionary.JPG?dl=0

Comment: Please accept the answer as correct and maybe open another issue for this error? It is difficult to understand code issues from comments

Answer (score 0):

Possible reason is you are using a String type variable and it contains some long value which results in crash .

You can put exception breakpoint to identify the exact line of code which is responsible for crash and fix it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have added the exception breakpoint and it gives me something like this:
TravelStories[16832:647878] - [__NSCFString longValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instan 0x14659d60

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. My dictionary passing me string value and i was saving in Int value. So in the init method  I did like this:

imgid = dictionary["imageId"]!
imageId = String(imgid as! String)!

It worked ... Thanks all :)